# NSSocketPortNameServer portForName:host: slow on Mavericks

Tags: macos, bonjour, distributed-objects, nsconnection, nssocketport

With Mavericks `[NSSocketPortNameServer portForName:host:]` now takes around 5 seconds to resolve localhost. It used to be much much faster, around 0.01 seconds.

My code is the same as in [Apple's Introduction to Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/distrobjects/Tasks/configuring.html).

I used to be able to start a child process and connect to it, in less than 0.1 seconds.
[My file manager](https://github.com/neoneye/newton-commander) runs several child processes and is currently defunct on Mavericks because of this. The app is not sandboxed.

I don't understand why `[NSSocketPortNameServer portForName:host:]` takes so long. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

**Any advice much appreciated?**

---

### Server code

This takes around 0.1 second to run.

```
NSSocketPort* port = [[NSSocketPort alloc] init];
NSConnection* connection = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:port sendPort:nil];
[[NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance] registerPort:port name:@"doug"];
```

---

### Client code that connects to the server

This takes 5 seconds on Mavericks.

This used to take around 0.1 seconds on Mountain Lion and Lion.

```
NSPort* port = [[NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance] portForName:@"doug" host:@"*"];
NSConnection* connection = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:nil sendPort:port];
```

I have also tried with `nil`, like this `[[NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance] portForName:name host:nil]`. It made no difference.

If I invalidate the connection and tries to connect again then `[[NSSocketPortNameServer sharedInstance] portForName:name host:nil]` also takes 5 seconds.

---

### What could be causing this

When I dump the DNS configuration with `scutil --dns`, I see that the local domain has a 5 second timeout. I suspect that this timeout was set to 0 seconds before Mavericks. I can't ask all users to reset this timeout, so I will continue investigating what to do on Mavericks to avoid this timeout.

Comment: could it be something to do with hardware or network topography rather than os... I don't know what your testing semantics are... but if it fails locally and tries externally over some network it seems like it would take much longer than .1s

Comment: @GradyPlayer that sounds likely. As if it tries to look the name up via DNS and then finally looks the name up locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

I ended up abandoning `-portForName:host:` and instead pass the port number via commandline to the child process.

The child process contacts the parent process this way:

```
int port = /* parent process' port number passed via command line */
NSSocketPort *port = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initRemoteWithTCPPort:port host:nil];
NSConnection* connection = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:nil sendPort:port];
```

The child process gets the port number from the parent process via commandline.
The parent process find its own port number via this category.

```
@implementation NSSocketPort (ObtainPortNumber)

-(int)portNumber {
        NSSocketNativeHandle sock = [self socket];
        NSData *address = self.address;
        if ([address length] != sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) {
                NSLog(@"NSSocketPort (ObtainPortNumber) - Mismatch size of address vs size of sockaddr_in.");
                return -1;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in addr = *((struct sockaddr_in*)[address bytes]);

        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len) == -1) {
                NSLog(@"NSSocketPort (ObtainPortNumber) - getsockname failed.");
                return -1;
        }

        int portNumber = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
        return portNumber;
}

@end
```